# Mongoose aggregate over date range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying mongoose aggregation. I want to get the total sum of a field in date range.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate

```
mymodel.aggregate({$match:{date:{$gte: fromDate, $lt: toDate}}},
                  {$project:{_id:0,date:1, count:1}},
                  {$group:{'_id':0,count:"$count"}}).exec(function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error Fetching model');
            console.log(err);
        }
        callback(false, data);
});
```

This is not working.

```
{ [MongoError: exception: the group aggregate field 'count' must be defined as an expression inside an object]
   name: 'MongoError',
   errmsg: 'exception: the group aggregate field \'count\' must be defined as an expression inside an object',
   code: 15951,
   ok: 0 }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not correct:

```
{$group:{'_id':0,count:"$count"}}
```

`$count` is not operator in the above, but just a field reference. You can not have "naked" field references in `$group`. You need to use an aggregation operator, like in:

```
{$group:{'_id':0,count:{"$sum": "$count"}}}
```

Please show a few sample documents, and I can update the answer in a more elaborate way.